# Search "ALL" public events using Facebook graph search API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Although this question has been asked before but that was an year before and not exactly what I wanted to ask. So, here it goes:

I am using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event to find all the events having a keyword "conference".

Question 1: I just get one page of results and the pagination link at the bottom of the page yield to a page with no data (just some structure). However, searching from my facebook I can see many many more events. How can I search for "ALL" (or a considerable number of events say 200+) ?

Question 2: In case, if the search results are limited how can I restrict to events from just one country. So, for example I am only interested in conferences that are in US and not the ones in Europe. How do I do that?

Question 3: How do I search for multiple keywords. Say I want to search for "conferences AND data".

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

To search for multiple keywords, use "+". In this case "conferences+data".

Answer (score -1):

about Question 1: note that q=conference means that you are searching for events with keyword conference in them. You are not searching events by category. If you want to search for all events you can use q=*, this will give you ALL public facebook events. They will not be filtered by location/distance. I have tried to limit the search by location & distance, but so far without any success.

Comment: Could you filter it by location and distance?

Answer (score -2):

add &limit=200 to your query string