# Search for all public events in an area

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to query all events in an area (a specific location + reach as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181480/how-can-i-query-public-facebook-events-by-location-city) is fine) and return event locations, no matter if via Graph Search or FQL. Problem: I only get a very small amount of events returned.

Searched rigorously, did not find exactly what I was looking for. Especially getting ALL events in an area seems to be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `limit=x` parameter to your requests?

Comment: I guess it is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608568/search-all-public-events-using-facebook-graph-search-api

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to retrieve "all" in this case. Facebook uses some kind of algorithm based on the limit and distance parameters and the density of locations/places/events in that area.

You can try to keep the distance low and limit beneath 1000, but it really depends on density, so for crowded areas you will get different results as for rural areas for example.

You can also try to create some kind of "GEO grid" of the area you are interested and move the center location by 1km every time.